# Interchanging limit and integral with Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem of a compactly supported differentiable function $f$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

Let $f \in C_0^m(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be a compactly supported function where $m \geq 1$. Then, what would be the precise usage of the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem when exchanging the limit and integral in $\lim_{h\to 0}\int_{\mathbb{R^n}}g(x)\frac{f(x + e_jh) - f(x)}{h}dx$, where $g$ is "nice-enough"? Do we take the maximum value of $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Apply MVT to $t \mapsto f(e_jt)$

Comment: Assuming $g\in L^1(\Bbb{R}^n)$, the dominating function can be taken to be $|g|\cdot\|Df\|_{\infty}$, i.e $|g|$ times the maximum of the first derivatives of $f$. You can get away with weaker assumptions though.

Comment: @geetha290krm Ah, you mean using essentially a Lipschitz property? Since $f'$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with a compact support?